# How to update the @Version field when executing a bulk update through Spring Data JPA

Tags: jpa, version, jpa-2.0, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data repositories and I have a problem I cant find the answer. My repository query is:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.firstName = 'blabla' WHERE u.loginName = 'admin'")
public int test();
```

And the entity `User` has an `javax.persistence.Version` annotated field:

```
 @Version
 private Long version;
```

When I execute the query the version field doesn't updates, but if instead of the  query i do:

```
User user = this.userRepository.findUserById(1L);
user.setFirstName("blabla");
this.userRepository.save(user);
```

the version field is updated. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Section 4.10 of the JPA 2.0 specification explicitly states:

> Bulk update maps directly to a database update operation, bypassing optimistic locking checks. Portable applications must manually update the value of the version column, if desired, and/or manually validate the value of the version column.

Generally speaking bulk updates and deletes pretty much bypass a lot of functionality that is applied by the persistence provider that you might be used to when simply saving an entity. Besides optimistic locking this includes the persistence provider managed cascading of persistence operations.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use optimistic locking, you need a `version` column first.

Now, if the bulk update statement does not increment the `version` column, a Lost Update anomaly can occur:

[image: Bulk update lost update]

Now, to avoid the Lost Update, you just need to increment the `version` column.

You can do it with any type of query.

### JPQL

```
int updateCount = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "update Post " +
    "set " +
    "   status = :newStatus," +
    "   version = version + 1 " +
    "where " +
    "   status = :oldStatus and " +
    "   lower(title) like :pattern")
.setParameter("oldStatus", PostStatus.PENDING)
.setParameter("newStatus", PostStatus.SPAM)
.setParameter("pattern", "%spam%")
.executeUpdate();
```

### Criteria API

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager
.getCriteriaBuilder();
 
CriteriaUpdate<Post> update = builder
.createCriteriaUpdate(Post.class);
 
Root<Post> root = update.from(Post.class);
 
Expression<Boolean> wherePredicate = builder
.and(
    builder.equal(
        root.get("status"),
        PostStatus.PENDING
    ),
    builder.like(
        builder.lower(root.get("title")),
        "%spam%"
    )
);
 
Path<Short> versionPath = root.get("version");
Expression<Short> incrementVersion = builder
.sum((short) 1, versionPath);
 
update
.set(root.get("status"), PostStatus.SPAM)
.set(versionPath, incrementVersion)
.where(wherePredicate);
 
int updateCount = entityManager
.createQuery(update)
.executeUpdate();
```

### Native SQL

```
UPDATE post
SET
  status = 2,
  version = version + 1
WHERE
  status = 0 AND 
  lower(title) LIKE '%spam%'
```

Once you increment the `version` column, the Lost Update will be prevented in the concurrent transactions that loaded the previous versions of the entities updated by the bulk statement:

[image: Bulk update with optimistic locking]

Comment: What if Alice's update query executes first? Seems like Bob's bulk update query will lead to a "Lost Update" this time.

Comment: Nope. If Alice updates first, the two transactions follow a serial execution, hence they are Serializable. Anomalies happen only when read and write operations are interleaved.

Comment: For that specific scenario, yes I agree. However on complex scenarios, e.g. a bulk select is executed, read data is used on some business logic and then updates are persisted to the database. I was referring to a flow something like this [https://cutt.ly/VXipROV](https://cutt.ly/VXipROV) which might be prevented with Pessimistic Locking [https://cutt.ly/MXisdK9](https://cutt.ly/MXisdK9)

Comment: That flow is unrealistic. A bulk update has a pre-defined predicate logic and doesn't require reading the data prior to the UPDATE. Optimistic locking is useful for read-modify-write scenarios that happen over user-think time, while a bulk update is associated with a batch processing task and represents a state change that shouldn't interfere with user interactions. For instance, deleting all records older than a date or updating the `is_deleted` column for all `event` records older than a date.